# Galera Cluster not bootstrapping

Tags: mariadb, cluster-computing, galera

I have been setting up a MariaDB Galera cluster. Everything has gone fine until I tried to bootstrap the first node. All the commands have been successful, but the status variables show that it is not working; the cluster size is zero and wsrep_ready is OFF. I set wsrep_on=ON but that didn't do anything. Any help is appreciated. I am using Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS operating system and MariaDB 10.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, not sure what the problem was, but after following a tutorial and using the sample config in it, the problem disappeared